# can use DB like Sqlite or sqlCe in WP7 (os 7.1)?

Tags: windows-phone-7, sqlite, sql-server-ce

is it possible to use DB like  Sqlite or sqlCe  for wp7 rather than isolated storage? wp6 i have used Sqlce but it was not supported now.

```
i have searched lot in google but couldn't get right one .
```

Please  help me to getting started with wp7 DB access using sqlite or sqlce?? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used UltraLite for modile development for quite some time now and it has not failed me yet. It's a great option.

http://download.sybase.com/pdfdocs/awg0900e/ulesen9.pdf

http://theopensourcery.com/sqlite.htm

Answer (score 1):

SQL CE is available in WP7 natively, though only via LINQ-to-SQL.

You might want to start with [How to: Create a Basic Local Database Application for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202876%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)